# Filtered count and total count without subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Suppose I have a table like this:

```
ID     Result
-------------
 1  ,  'pass'
 2  ,  'pass'
 3  ,  'fail'
 4  ,  'fail'
 5  ,  'fail'
 6 ,   'fail'
```

Is there any simple way to find `COUNT WHERE result = 'fail' AND total COUNT`.

Expected output:

```
FailCount    TotalCount
-----------------------
    4            6
```

Yes, we can do this using subquery like this:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(result) FROM t WHERE result='fail') AS FAILCount
, COUNT(result)
AS TotalCount FROM t;
```

But is there any way to do like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(WHERE Result='fail') , COUNT(Result) FROM ...
```

[I am trying in this fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18571/12)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**ANSI SQL**

```
SELECT 
   SUM(CASE WHEN Result='fail' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) , 
   COUNT(*) FROM ...
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18571/3)

**MySQL Specific** (as pointed by eggyal)

```
SELECT 
       SUM(Result='fail') , 
       COUNT(*) FROM ...
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18571/5)

Comment: In MySQL, one can abbreviate it to `SUM(Result='fail')`.

Comment: @eggyal Thanks. You commented exactly what I wanted in MySQL.

Comment: @eggyal And another way is mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159128/filtered-count-and-total-count-without-subquery/12159370#12159370) using `COUNT`

Answer (score 5):

And yes we can also use `COUNT` like this:

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(CASE WHEN Result='fail' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) , 
   COUNT(*) FROM ...
```

[See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a348/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   SUM(CASE WHEN Result='fail' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as FailCount, 
   COUNT(Result) as TotalCount FROM table_name
```